# Opening a phone contact list and then selecting a single contact

Tags: android

I am using this code to open my contact list and then select a single contact to display in my UI. I am able to open my contact list, but when I am clicking on any contact, the program is crashing.

```
etphone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            // startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            Intent pb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pb, 1);

        }
    });
```

My `onActivityForResult`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null,
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String number = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            TextView tv;
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            tv.setText(number);

        }
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r10-272B2B434F414D37413143/10 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.sriyank.locationmessenger/com.sriyank.locationmessenger.SecondPage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'data1' does not exist
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3209)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'data1' does not exist
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:302)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
12-11 11:05:48.969: E/AndroidRuntime(16292):    at com.sriyank.locationmessenger.SecondPage.onActivityResult(SecondPage.java:59)
```

Comment: Where is your logcat error ?

Comment: It is hard to find the problem with this only word `Crashing`. Please post your log cat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code set up the 3 text view as contant name and phone number.
Set your button click listener
Set the intent as mentioned.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.l1:

        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        break;
    case R.id.l2:

        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

        break;
    case R.id.l3:

        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);

        break;

    }
}
```

This is onActivity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver()
                        .query(uri,
                                new String[] {
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME },
                                null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    String Name = c.getString(1);

                    if (requestCode == 1) {

                        tvname1.setText(Name);
                        tvphone1.setText(number);

                    } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                        tvname2.setText(Name);
                        tvphone2.setText(number);

                    } else if (requestCode == 3) {
                        tvname3.setText(Name);
                        tvphone3.setText(number);

                    }

                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not initialize your views in `onActivityResult` may be the issue will be because of your `Textview` initialization. Declare it in your `onCreate()`. Remove the `TextView` initialization from your below method and initialize it in your onCreate() and check.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null,
                    null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            String number = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            //TextView tv;
            //tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); //remove this lines.

            tv.setText(number);

        }
    }

}
```

**EDITED:**

Try out using the below code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_picker);

    // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    // and the intent.setType
  etphone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                
        }
    });
}
```

now, as soon as the user selects a contact (and probably chooses one of several phone numbers), you can retrieve the data the normal way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (uri != null) {
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME },
                        null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String number = c.getString(0);
                    String Name=c.getString(1);
                   Toast.makeText(this, number + Name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out my updated answer and try using that code which i have mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried my code ? And make sure you have given the READ_CONTACT permission in your manifest.

Comment: ya thanx buddy. Now it is working. What if i want to get the name of the contact too.  What should i add?

Comment: Check i have updated my answer to get the name of contact by adding another field into the array of String in onActivityResult.